# What is the difference between void and return even though I can get same output on both?

Tags: java, methods, return-value, void, return-type

i made a small program for summing two numbers
if i used a void type method it will be like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("enter x");
        int x = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter y");
       int y = input.nextInt();
       getSum(x,y);
    }

    public static void getSum(int x, int y)
    {
        int sum = x + y;
        System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
    } }
```

here if i used a method that returns a value i will get same output!

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("enter x");
        int x = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter y");
       int y = input.nextInt();
       int r = getSum(x,y);
        System.out.println("sum = " + r);
    }
    public static int getSum(int x, int y)
    {
        int sum = x + y;
        return sum;
    }}
```

so i'm confused what is the benefit of returning a value if i can finish my program with a void type method?

Comment: in your case: no benefit.

Comment: Well in the first program, method `getSum(...)` prints the statement, while in the second, it only returns the sum and printing it to screen is done within the `main` method. You can find more information regarding return types in [this tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html).

Comment: What if you need to do something with the sum value after it's calculated? If you try to use the sum value to perform some other calculation in `getSum`, it'll violate the method contract as that method should **ONLY** get the sum. In that case, you'd need to return the value for it to be used elsewhere in another calculation. In your particular case, you really don't need to return the value since you're simply printing the sum. However, it is improper design as the method is named `getSum` so it should allow the caller to retrieve the sum value (by returning it).

Comment: What's the point of `getSum` when we have `+`? Design choices. In your case, removing the `println` from `getSum` will increase the usability of `getSum`. If that method prints, then you'd only use it in areas that required the sum to be printed immediately. If you removed `println`, you (or anyone you allow to use this method) could reuse `getSum` for other things which may not prefer the sum to be printed immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is not to get the result but the way we get the result

consider

```
public static void getSum(int x, int y)
    {
        int sum = x + y;
        System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
    }
```

will print the output to the screen after calculation

but when we use return 
as you have done it later

```
public static int getSum(int x, int y)
    {
        int sum = x + y;
        return sum;
    }
```

this function will respond back the sum. that sum can be stored in a variable 
can be used afterwards
like in recursion

Answer (score 0):

In small programs, you won't get the difference but while writing the big programs you have to make several functions which are being called several times and you may need the output of one function into other. 
In that case, you will require return so that the output of one function can be used into other.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

When you use the keyword `void` it means that method doesn't return anything at all. If you declare a return type different to void at the method statement instead, that method must return obligatorily a valid value to the declared return type using the keyword `return` followed by a variable/value to send back to the class that called the method.

[Defining methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) here you have the java documentation for a method declaration

Answering your question, in small programs that work with primitive values it doesn't really matter but in complex program when you usually need to return specifics object types, i.e an ArrayList or actually an instance of a class you created you can't simply put it into a `System.out.println` and send it to the console, mostly you'll want to get something from a method and that something usually can be a more complex object than an integer or a string, the way to get that something is through the `return` type defined by the method's statement.

A common use of return types is when your method is static and it can't interact with the non-static instance variables of the class, this type of static methods usually get values from their arguments, do a certain kind of progress and then return a result that the method's caller can use.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that, if you're calling getSum() method with a return type in any other class.. you would get a returned value which can be used for further processing. .
Where as in void that's not possible... Hope this helps... Reply if any doubts..

Answer (score 0):

I can understand why you have this question.

First of all, you should know that in real development, we do not use console logs.

```
System.out.Println();
```

This is used only for debugging and that too in very rare cases.

The whole point of a function is to take some input and convert to something else.

So,

```
public static int getSum(int x, int y) {
 return x+y;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.out.Println(getSum(5,10));
}
```

This is the better solution.

Best Regards,

Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

Returning a value enables you to use that value in whichever way you want, including printing it or assigning it to  variable for further processing. If on the other hand you print the value in the method and not return anything, i.e. making the method of type `void`, then that's all you can do with that method.